# How should I define a character array (like char*) for translation into all languages?

Tags: c++, string, arduino, translation

I have to convert a custom String class into a class that is capable of handling all languages.

Currently, the string class looks something like this:

```
String WString
{
    public:
    char* data;
    // Many, many functions for manipulating, resizing, copying,
    // and otherwise handling the characters in "data"
};
```

My first through was to change data to short* data, or even unsigned int* data... but what I'm looking for is advice and a resource for best practices.

The software outputs to a bitmap printer, of all things, so I will literally be taking small png files for each character and outputting them to the printer.

What's the best format to use for *data, and are there any good online resources to read about how to properly handle languages like Chinese, Korean, or Japanese?

Comment: You don't want to write this yourself. Find a unicode library. Out of the different unicode versions, UTF8 is commonly used nowadays. Do note that C++ doesn't have the best unicode support / libraries.

Comment: What encoding will your string data be in ?

Comment: For "all languages", don't use `char` data type.  Many languages have more than 256 encodings, so you'll need something larger.

Comment: justin: Using a different library isn't an option.  This sits on a very small arduino device and I basically have to strip out anything that's not specifically needed to make things fit.

@Richard Critten, honestly, it's going to be referencing bitmap images that will make up custom fonts.  But to give the customer a spec for those images, I need to know a little more about how someone would provide those bitmapped fonts.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews, yes, the current code is char*, I am trying to decide what it has to be converted to.  I'm working within strict memory requirements, however, and need the smallest possible storage space that would be able to hold, say, a Chinese sentence.

Comment: The standard _"`Wchar`"_ data type is `uint16_t` IIRC. However you should use at least some basic Unicode conversion library for certain charset representations like `libiconv` or similar (it is highly configurable to leave irrelevant conversions out).

Comment: @Raptisoft Wait, you mean you need to provide your own font definitions for an arduino terminal representation?

Comment: I'd still use UTF8, keep the string data external, and then write something that takes those external data files and converts them into a lookup to your bitmap in your custom string print then.  Lots of work.  We've had to do this for years on older Nintendo Handhelds (GBC/GBA/DS...)

Comment: @user0042 ... yep.  It's a tiny device and the user basically wants to download customer feedback from the internet and immediately print them out-- on a dot matrix printer (yes I asked him why not just read them on the internet).  This is literally an old RS232 printer from the early 90's that he's managed to connect up... all I basically have to do is take text from the internet and point it at a bitmap to shove at the printer.

Comment: _@Raptisoft_ Oh boy. The only additional advice I have to add is have a look into the [_Flyweight Pattern_](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/flyweight) and glyphs. As @Michael mentioned loads of work, no easy way out.